# What grammar form is 전담해서 해요?

Tags: grammar

I have this sentence in my textbook:

이제부터 나는 주말엔 손도 까딱 안 할 테니까 당신이 아예 집안일을 전담해서 해.

What is the grammar of 전담해서 해? Or what is the concrete logic behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (해서 해요) isn't actually a verb pattern; it's two separate clauses, the second clause consisting only of "해" (meaning "do"). (The first clause, 집안일을 전담해서, includes the ~아/어서 pattern, which gives a cause or reason for doing what follows).

전담하다 means "take responsibility for", so the ending means "take responsibility for the housework and do [it]" -the "it" word is elided here in Korean though.  The ~아/어서 pattern here I've translated as "and", but the second part is a result of the first, so 아/어서 is appropriate - take responsibility for the housework and (therefore) do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a standard verb + ~아/어서 pattern. In this usage, you could change it to -고 and the meaning would still be conveyed. The first usage explained [here](https://www.koreantopik.com/2018/01/l1g19-av-grammar-1-and-in-order-to-2.html)
is similar.

> 3. 내일 친구를 만나서 같이 커피를 마실 거예요.
>    Tomorrow I will meet my friend and drink coffee together.